# keepass2 under debian wont open an url

Tags: password-management

i have just installed keepass2 and keefox, too. It's working fine except for the fact that it fails to open an URL from within keepass2. So when I try to open an URL (for which an entry exists in keepass2) it tries to run a new instance of firefox rather than opening a new window/tab within it.

Any clues how to fix this?

Comment: Is this behavior limited to Keepass, or does this happen with other applications as well? If you would click on a link in a mail client like Thunderbird, will this happen as well? If so, this is not a problem with Keepass, but with Debian.

Comment: thx. fixed. it was indeed a debian prob.